# SQL Query Transform Derived Table to normal Join (indexed view)

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the followin SQL Query with a derived table and I can't create the CLUSTERED INDEX of my Indexed View because of that. So I have to convert the derived table to normal join.

```
SELECT
......
FROM 
dbo.invoice i

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT SUM(amount) as servicesamount
    ,ise.invoiceuid
    ,ise.episodeuid
    ,ise.memberuid
    ,ev.caseuid

    FROM dbo.invoice_services ise
    JOIN dbo.invoice inv on inv.invoiceuid = ise.invoiceuid
    JOIN dbo.event ev ON ev.eventuid = ise.episodeuid -- JOIN IN ORDER TO BRING EVENT INVOCIES ONLY (DENTAL INVOICES COULD EXIST)
    GROUP BY ise.invoiceuid,ise.episodeuid,ise.memberuid,ev.caseuid

) ise ON ise.invoiceuid = i.invoiceuid
```

Any clue on how to convert the

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount) as servicesamount
        ,ise.invoiceuid
        ,ise.episodeuid
        ,ise.memberuid
        ,ev.caseuid

        FROM dbo.invoice_services ise
        JOIN dbo.invoice inv on inv.invoiceuid = ise.invoiceuid
        JOIN dbo.event ev ON ev.eventuid = ise.episodeuid -- JOIN IN ORDER TO BRING EVENT INVOCIES ONLY (DENTAL INVOICES COULD EXIST)
        GROUP BY ise.invoiceuid,ise.episodeuid,ise.memberuid,ev.caseuid

    ) ise
```

to normal join?

Appreciate it!!

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't just mean turning it into an `INNER JOIN`.  Don't know anything about indexed views - can you use a CTE instead?  But aside from that - do you have an actual performance issue (that means the view needs to be indexed, instead of just a regular view backed by indexed tables)?  Oh, you should be able to remove the reference to `dbo.invoice` inside the sub-query.

Comment: what happens is that I can have a derived table example: Left join (select....) it should be something streight like : left join dbo.invoice_services....

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  And what about the rest of my questions?

Comment: Looks like you have two problems, 1) the outer (left) join, and 2) the fact that you're trying to sum the records.  If you can't stick that in a CTE (documentation is ambiguous), you might not be able to.  Now, the _subselect_ could be part of an indexed view, but the whole thing might not be able to... what were you doing in the outer query - could the whole thing be done as the **subselect**?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT ...
  ,SUM(amount) as servicesamount
  ,ise.invoiceuid
  ,ise.episodeuid
  ,ise.memberuid
  ,ev.caseuid
  ,...
FROM dbo.invoice inv 
 LEFT JION dbo.invoice_services ise ON inv.invoiceuid = ise.invoiceuid
 LEFT JOIN dbo.event ev ON ev.eventuid = ise.episodeuid
GROUP BY inv..., ise.invoiceuid,ise.episodeuid,ise.memberuid,ev.caseuid
```